# javascript logic to append/prepend div on html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a very basic web app that pulls recipe data back from an API. The data is rendered via being pushed to an html template defined in the javascript file. The layout is controlled via a float-grid in CSS.

The code portion that renders the result and pushes to the template:

```
function displayRecipeSearchData(data) {
  var results = ' ';
  if (data.hits.length) {
    data.hits.forEach(function(item) {
      results += template.item(item);
    });
  }
  else {
    results += '<p> No results </p>';
  }
  $('#js-search-results').html(results);
}
```

The html template through which responses are displayed:

```
const template = {
  item: function(item) {
    return '<div class ="col-4">' +
             '<div class ="result">' +
               '<div class="recipelabel">' +
                 '<div class="reclist">' + item.recipe.ingredientLines + '</div><!-- end reclist -->' +
                  '<p class="label">' + item.recipe.label + '</p>' +
                  '<div class="thumbnail">' + 
                    '<a href="'+ httpsTransform(item.recipe.url) + '" target="_blank">' +
                      '<img src="' + item.recipe.image + '"alt="' + item.recipe.label + '">' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '<div class="recipesource">' +
                      '<p class="source">' + item.recipe.source + '</p>' +
                    '</div><!-- end recipesource -->' +
                  '</div><!-- end thumbnail -->' +
                '</div><!-- end recipelabel -->' +
              '</div><!-- end result -->' + 
            '</div><!-- end col-4 -->';
  }
};
```

I am trying to change the logic in the displayRecipeSearchData function such that, for each group of three results, a `<div></div>` surrounds the block of three results. This is so the rows/columns always work in the flex grid. I have tried several ways but have yet to get the syntax/logic correct. Would an if statement nested in the existing statement be effective?

```
if(i % 3 === 0 ){ results. += '<div class="row">''</div>'}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another variable for storing one row of HTML:

```
function displayRecipeSearchData(data) {
  var results = ' ', row = '';
  if (data.hits.length) {
    data.hits.forEach(function(item, i) {
      row += template.item(item);
      if (i % 3 == 2) { // wrap row and add to result
        results += '<div class="row">' + row + '</div>';
        row = '';
      }
    });
    if (row.length) { // flush remainder into a row
      results += '<div class="row">' + row + '</div>';
    }
  }
  else {
    results += '<p> No results </p>';
  }
  $('#js-search-results').html(results);
}
```

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you are definitely doing this the hard way in my opinion.

instead of manually writing the template as a string and trying to inject the string at the right place (potentially creating invalid html) you should use javascripts built-in element creation.  also it'll be more modular to create children in their own functions. It will also be much easier to use a function instead of an object to hold your object creator. My version may have a lot more code, but it will be much easier to modify in the long run

```
const Itemizer = function(){
  this.items = [];
  const createEl = function(elType, classes, attributes, text, html){
    let el = document.createElement(elType)
    for(let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
      el.classList.add(classes[i]
    }
    for(let attr in attributes){
      el.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr])
    }
    if(text){
      el.innerText = text
    }
    if(html){
      el.innerHTML = html
    }
    return el
  };

  const createThumbnail = function(url, image, alt, source){
    let thumbnail = createEl("DIV", ["thumbnail"]),
        link = createEl("A", [], {href: httpsTransform(url)}),
        img = createEl("IMG", [], {src: image, alt: label});
        rSource = createRecipeSource(source)
    link.appendChild(img);
    thumbnail.appendChild(link);
    thumbnail.appendChild(rSource)
    return thumbnail
  };

  const createRecipeSource = function(source){
    let wrapper = createEl("DIV", ["recipe-source"]);
    wrapper.appendChild(createEl("P", ["source"], {}, source))
    return wrapper
  }

  const createRecipeLabel = function({
    recipe: {
      ingredientLines,
      label,
      url,
      source
    }
  }){
    let labelWrapper = createEl("DIV", ["recipe-label"),
        ingredients = createEl("DIV", ["rec-list"], {}, false, ingredientLines),
        recipeLabel = createEl("P", ["label"], {}, label),
        thumbnail = createThumbnail(url, image, label, source)
    labelWrapper.appendChild(ingredients)
    labelWrapper.appendChild(recipeLabel)
    labelWrapper.appendChild(thumbnail)
    return labelWrapper
  }

  const createNewItem = function(data){
    let columnWrapper = createEl("DIV", ["col-4"]),
        result = createEl("DIV", ["result"]),
        label = createRecipeLabel(data)

    columnWrapper.appendChild(result)
    result.appendChild(label)
    this.items.push(columnWrapper)
    return columnWrapper
  }.bind(this)

  const getItems = function(){
   return this.items
  }.bind(this)

  const getRows = function(){
    const rows = []
    let row;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
      const item = this.items[i]
      if(i % 3 === 0){
        row = createEl("DIV", ["row"])
        rows.push(row)
      }
      row.appendChild(item)
    }
    return rows;
  }.bind(this)

  return {
    add: createNewItem,
    get: getItems,
    rows: getRows
  }
}
```

You can then use the function like so:

```
const template = new Itemizer()
function displayRecipeSearchData(data) {
  let rows
  if (data.hits.length) {
    for(let i = 0; i < data.hits.length; i++){
      template.add(data.hits[i])
    }
    rows = template.rows()
  } else {
    const p = document.createElement("P")
    p.innerText = "No Results")
    rows = [p]
  }
  const resultsWrapper = document.getElementById("js-search-results");
  for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    resultsWrapper.appendChild(rows[i])
  }
}
```

it's also good form to separate css classes with hyphens, so I replaced a few of your class names to reflect that

It's also important to note that you don't actually need more than 1 row. if you wrap all of your items in one `row` section columns will automatically overflow to the next row when they hit the grid limit

My last note is never use target blank. it goes against proper UX, and creates security holes in your application. if your users need to open in a new tab they can hold `ctrl` or click "open in new tab"